# Refactoring an angular component with RxJS to use signal

Tags: angular, rxjs, signals

I am currently refactoring an Angular component that uses RxJS, aiming to implement signals. The component's requirements are:

1. Retrieve and render a business object.
2. Display a loading indicator.
3. Show an error screen if there's an issue, with a retry/refresh option.

##### Current Implementation

Here's the current implementation of my component:

```
class BusinessDetailPage implements OnInit {
  business: Business = null;
  loading = true;
  error = false;

  trigger$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(/** ... */) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    from(this.trigger$)
      .pipe(
        untilDestroyed(this),
        tap(() => (this.loading = true)),
        switchMap(() =>
          this.businessService
            .getBusiness(parseInt(this.route.snapshot.params.id))
            .pipe(
              first(),
              catchError(() => {
                this.error = true;
                this.loading = false;
                return of(null);
              })
            )
        )
      )
      .subscribe((business) => {
        this.business = business;
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }

  retry() {
    this.trigger$.next();
  }
}
```

##### Approach 1

Inspired by an example I found ([signal-error-example](https://github.com/joshuamorony/signal-error-example/blob/main/src/app/shared/utils/toSignalWithError.ts)), I refactored my component as follows:

```js
export class BusinessDetailPage {
  trigger$ = new Subject<void>();
  business = toSignalWithError(this.fetchBusiness());
  isLoading = computed(() => !this.business()?.value && !this.business()?.error);

  constructor(/** ... */) {
    this.trigger$.next();
  }

  refresh() {
    this.trigger$.next();
  }

  private fetchBusiness() {
    return from(this.trigger$).pipe(
      untilDestroyed(this),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.businessService.getBusiness(
          parseInt(this.route.snapshot.params.id)
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This approach looks clean, but I'm unsure how to effectively display the loading indicator, particularly when an error or content is already present.

##### Approach 2

Alternatively, I considered a slightly more verbose approach:

```js
export class BusinessDetailPage {
  trigger$ = new Subject<void>();
  business = toSignal(this.fetchBusiness());
  error = signal(false);
  isLoading = signal(false);

  constructor(/** ... */) {
    this.trigger$.next();
  }

  refresh() {
    this.trigger$.next();
  }

  private fetchBusiness() {
    return from(this.trigger$).pipe(
      untilDestroyed(this),
      tap(() => {
        this.error.set(false);
        this.isLoading.set(true);
      }),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.businessService
          .getBusiness(parseInt(this.route.snapshot.params.id))
          .pipe(
            catchError(() => {
              this.error.set(true);
              return of(null);
            }),
            finalize(() => this.isLoading.set(false))
          )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This approach seems to cover all requirements but my goal was to derive (compute) the `isLoading` from the signal, which is not the case anymore.

##### Questions

1. Between these two approaches, which is considered best practice in terms of code efficiency and readability?
2. Is there a more optimized way to handle the loading and error states in the context of using Signals?
3. Any suggestions on improving the refactoring process for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best scenario is to combine rxjs and signals for a sake of efficient reactivity.

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wnsjnn) bro.

Some pieces of the code:

**Service**:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BusinessService {
  businessData = signal<any | null>(null);
  loading = signal(false);
  error = signal(false);

  router = inject(Router);
  http = inject(HttpClient);

  #loadingQueue = new Subject<number>();

  loadingQueue = this.#loadingQueue.pipe(
    switchMap((id) => {
      this.error.set(false);
      this.loading.set(true);
      const simulateError = Math.random() < 0.5;
      return this.http
        .get(
          `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos${
            simulateError ? 'x' : ''
          }/${id}`
        )
        .pipe(
          catchError(() => {
            this.error.set(true);
            return of(null);
          }),
          tap((response) => {
            this.businessData.set(response);
          }),
          finalize(() => this.loading.set(false))
        );
    })
  );

  loadBusiness(id: number) {
    this.loading.set(true);
    this.#loadingQueue.next(id);
  }

  changeBusiness() {
    this.router.navigate(['business', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)]);
  }
}
```

**Component**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-business',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './business.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  imports: [NgIf, JsonPipe],
})
export class BusinessComponent {
  id = input.required<number>();
  businessService = inject(BusinessService);

  constructor() {
    this.businessService.loadingQueue.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed()).subscribe();
    effect(() => {
      const id = this.id();
      untracked(() => this.businessService.loadBusiness(id));
    });
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<h3>The business {{ id() }}</h3>
<h5>
  <button
    [disabled]="businessService.loading()"
    (click)="businessService.changeBusiness()"
  >
    Change business
  </button>
</h5>
<p *ngIf="businessService.error()" style="color: red; font-weight: bolder;">
  Error occured!
</p>
<pre *ngIf="businessService.businessData() as data">{{ data | json }}</pre>
```

**Bootrapping the App**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(
      [
        {
          path: '',
          pathMatch: 'full',
          redirectTo: 'business/1',
        },
        {
          path: 'business/:id',
          loadComponent: () =>
            import('./business.component').then((c) => c.BusinessComponent),
        },
      ],
      withComponentInputBinding()
    ),
    provideHttpClient(),
  ],
});
```